# How to: migrate "real" (not Chrome) Google bookmarks from one account into another

Tags: google-workspace, google-bookmarks, migration

Is it possible to move Google bookmarks from one account to another? My GApps domain now allows me to use Google Bookmarks. Previously I've had to use a 'real' Google account to store these, and I want to consolidate under my apps account (and I have to, basically, since I can only have a single sign-on in a browser).

However, I can't seem to find way of moving the bookmarks. I can export them from [www.google.com/bookmarks](http://www.google.com/bookmarks), but the 'import' link just sends me to some help which instructs me to use the Google Chrome sync.

I don't want to do that, since there are plugins that allow me to access my bookmarks from Firefox etc.

(Note that this is a copy of my unanswered question on SuperUSer; I figured this was a better forum for it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to export and then import it into Firefox. Then, use the Google Firefox toolbar to sync it to another Google account. It's a round about way, but that's what's recommended.

If you don't want to meddle with your existing bookmarks on Firefox, you might want to import them into a new [Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/managing+profiles) created for this purpose.

Comment: Do you know if this will preserve the labels on (re)import?